# Python str.slice in apply function get AttributeError

Tags: python, pandas, data-manipulation

I have a dataset like this:

```
col1      col2
12345        N
450540       Y
356487       Y
000123       Y
111564       Y
```

```
df['col3'] = df[['col1', 'col2']].apply(lambda x: "N" if (x['col1'].str[:3]) in ['000','111'] else \
                                                x['col2'], axis = 1)
```

However, I got this error: `AttributeError: ("'str' object has no attribute 'str'", 'occurred at index 0')`

The data type for `col1` is `object`:

```
df['col1'].dtypes
> dtype('O')
```

Any suggestion on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `lambda` in your `apply` takes each row individually. So `x['col1']` is a `str`, which does not have the attribute `str`. So just modify the `lambda` so that it only slices:

```py
df['col3'] = df[['col1', 'col2']].apply(lambda x: "N" if x['col1'][:3] in ('000', '111') else x['col2'], axis=1)

df
     col1 col2 col3
0   12345    N    N
1  450540    Y    Y
2  356487    Y    Y
3  000123    Y    N
4  111564    Y    N
```

### Can I use `str.slice`?

Yes, you can use it to define a mask like this:

```py
mask = df.col1.str.slice(stop=3).apply(lambda x:  x in ('000', '111'))

mask
0    False
1    False
2    False
3     True
4     True

# The default condition is that 'col3' takes the values in 'col2'
df['col3'] = df['col2']

# Then use `loc` to switch the values based on the mask
df['col3'].loc[(mask)] = 'N'

df
     col1 col2 col3
0   12345    N    N
1  450540    Y    Y
2  356487    Y    Y
3  000123    Y    N
4  111564    Y    N
```

As an alternative, it might just be better to use `str.contains` with a regex:

```py
mask = df['col1'].str.contains('^(000|111)', regex=True)

mask
0    False
1    False
2    False
3     True
4     True
Name: col1, dtype: bool
```

Comment: Can I use `.slice()` on this?